# Get top 5 salaries from each department using HQL/Hibernate Criteria

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I amd trying to write a HQL/Hibernate criteria to get the top 5 salaries from each department.
Can someone help am able to write the sql query?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        employee_id,
        department_id,
        salar dense_rank() OVER ( partition by department_id ORDER BY salary desc) as ranking
    FROM
    employees) a
WHERE a.ranking <=5
```

My first question is, does `dense_rank` function exist in hibernate?
If you guys can solve this please help out.

TIA

Comment: I don't think HQL supports the analytic functions (partly because not all underlying supported databases would support them).  If your particular database does support them, you can always execute a raw query.  Or maybe write a stored proc.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen